# How do I make a timer that when it is finished, it calls a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

im trying to create a rock paper scissors game that when you click either rock paper or scissors, the computer chooses weather rock paper or scissors randomly an gives you a result. Im trying to make it so when i press either rock paper or scissors I have to wait 10 seconds (and a timer will pop up of 10 seconds) before it gives me the result of what the computer picked.

I'm trying to create a timer that when finished, it calls another function. The timer is supposed to be 10 seconds long. I have tried using setTimeout() and setInterval() but none of those seemed to work with me as i dint know how to use them properly.  This is the code I have for it now. (Im learning ik its pretty bad)

```
let i = 10 
function myTimer() {
  i--
   console.log(i)
   timerDown.innerText = i
   if (i === 0) {
      timerDown.innerText = ''
     algo()
     i = 10
   }

}
```

As Well, Here is the rest of the code.

```
// rock paper siccors
const timerDown = document.getElementById("XP")
const initialMessage = document.getElementById("initialMessage")
const userChoice = document.getElementById("userChoice")
const message = document.getElementById("message")
const computerCard = document.getElementById("computerres")
let paper = false
let rock = false
let scissors = false

//making butons work

initialMessage.innerHTML = 'Rock Paper or Scissors?'

function drawrock() {
rock = true;
initialMessage.innerHTML = ''
userChoice.innerText = 'You chose rock!'
console.log('user has chosen rock');
startCountdown()

};

function drawpaper() {
paper = true 
console.log('user has chosen paper')
initialMessage.innerHTML = ''
userChoice.innerHTML = 'You chose paper!'
startCountdown()

}

function drawscissors() {
scissors = true
userChoice.innerHTML = 'You chose scissors!'
initialMessage.innerHTML = ''
console.log('user has chosen scissors')
setInterval()

}



let i = 10 
function myTimer() {
  i--
   console.log(i)
   timerDown.innerText = i
   if (i === 0) {
      timerDown.innerText = ''
     algo()
     clearInterval(myVar);
     i = 10
   }

}

// make an algorithim that randomizes gameplay

function algo() {
    let computerLogic = ['paper', 'rock', 'scissors'];

   
let Xlogic = computerLogic[Math.floor(Math.random()*computerLogic.length)];

console.log('CL ' + Xlogic)

//paper
   if (Xlogic === 'paper' && paper === true){
     console.log('draw')
     message.innerText = "Draw"
    paper = false
    rock = false
    scissors = false
    computerCard.innerText = "The compueter picked " + Xlogic + '!'
    }
   
   else if (Xlogic === 'paper' && scissors === true) {
       console.log('user won')
       message.innerText = "You won!"
       paper = false
    rock = false
    scissors = false
    computerCard.innerText = "The compueter picked " + Xlogic + '!'
   }

   else if (Xlogic === 'paper' && rock === true) {
       console.log('pc won')
       message.innerText = "Computer Won"
       paper = false
    rock = false
    scissors = false
    computerCard.innerText = "The compueter picked " + Xlogic + '!'
   }

   //rock
   else if (Xlogic === 'rock' && rock === true){
    console.log('draw')
    message.innerText = "Draw"
    paper = false
    rock = false
    scissors = false
    computerCard.innerText = "The compueter picked " + Xlogic + '!'
   }
  
  else if (Xlogic === 'rock' && scissors === true) {
      console.log('pc won')
      message.innerText = "Computer Won"
      paper = false
    rock = false
    scissors = false
    computerCard.innerText = "The compueter picked " + Xlogic + '!'
  }

  else if (Xlogic === 'rock' && paper === true) {
      console.log('user won')
      message.innerText = "You won!"
      paper = false
    rock = false
    scissors = false
    computerCard.innerText = "The compueter picked " + Xlogic + '!'
  }

  //scissors
  else if (Xlogic === 'scissors' && scissors === true){
    console.log('draw')
    message.innerText = "Draw"
    paper = false
    rock = false
    scissors = false
    computerCard.innerText = "The compueter picked " + Xlogic + '!'
   }
  
  else if (Xlogic === 'scissors' && rock === true) {
      console.log('user won')
      message.innerText = "You won!"
      paper = false
    rock = false
    scissors = false
    
    computerCard.innerText = "The compueter picked " + Xlogic + '!'
  }

  else if (Xlogic === 'scissors' && paper === true) {
      console.log('pc won')
      message.innerText = "Computer Won"
      paper = false
    rock = false
    scissors = false
    computerCard.innerText = "The compueter picked " + Xlogic + '!'
  }




}
```

Some help would be great.
Cheers
(again i just started programming and the code is not good at all)

Comment: setTimeout() may be better in this project than setInterval() because setInterval will repeat the code over and over again in that specific seconds while setTimeout only does it once.Also, your setInterval function doesn't have a callback or a second to run that callback. Here is an example: setTimeout(function(){console.log("This will run in 1 second");}, 1000);. Note: 1000 MS = 1S in JS.

Answer (score 1):

for setting a timer and running a function (a callback) you can use the setTimeout function.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  // code to run here    
}, time till you run it in ms)
```

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout()` is probably the best option here.
The way `setTimeout()` works is as follows:

```
setTimeout(function[, delay, arg1, arg2...]);

// For example:
setTimeout(myFunction, 3000, "abc", 123);
```

The example function would execute `myFunction` after 3 seconds with the arguments `"abc"` and `123`.

If you don't want to use a separate function, you can instead use arrow notation to just include the code you want to run.

```
setTimeout(() => {return "error"}, 3000);
```

Note that `setTimeout()` doesn't stop other functions from being run during the duration, so

```
setTimeout(() => {console.log("Goodbye, World!")}, 10000);
console.log("Hello, World!");
```

would print

```
Hello, World!
// ≈10 seconds later
Goodbye, World!
```

For more information, you can read the MDN docs for `setTimeout()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the explanation helped out a lot!